# Android Crosswalk org.xwalk.core.R$x.xxx is not found

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I Have Cordova applcation and I tried to integrate with [Crosswalk 9 (Stable)](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/downloads.html) for Android.

So my project has dependancy with `framework` and `walk_core_library` sub projects located under:

```
crosswalk-cordova-9.38.208.10-arm/framework
```

However when application starts I get following warning:

```
12-16 17:18:46.727: W/XWalkInternalResources(8280): org.xwalk.core.R$style.AutofillPopupWindow is not found.
12-16 17:18:46.727: W/XWalkInternalResources(8280): org.xwalk.core.R$layout.autofill_text is not found.
12-16 17:18:46.737: W/XWalkInternalResources(8280): org.xwalk.core.R$id.autofill_label is not found.
12-16 17:18:46.737: W/XWalkInternalResources(8280): org.xwalk.core.R$id.autofill_menu_text is not found.
12-16 17:18:46.737: W/XWalkInternalResources(8280): org.xwalk.core.R$id.autofill_popup_window is not found.
12-16 17:18:46.737: W/XWalkInternalResources(8280): org.xwalk.core.R$id.autofill_sublabel is not found.
12-16 17:18:46.737: W/XWalkInternalResources(8280): org.xwalk.core.R$drawable.autofill_popup_background is not found.
12-16 17:18:46.737: W/XWalkInternalResources(8280): org.xwalk.core.R$drawable.autofill_popup_background_down is not found.
12-16 17:18:46.737: W/XWalkInternalResources(8280): org.xwalk.core.R$drawable.autofill_popup_background_up is not found.
12-16 17:18:46.737: W/XWalkInternalResources(8280): org.xwalk.core.R$dimen.autofill_text_divider_height is not found.
12-16 17:18:46.737: W/XWalkInternalResources(8280): org.xwalk.core.R$dimen.autofill_text_height is not found.
12-16 17:18:46.747: W/XWalkInternalResources(8280): org.xwalk.core.R$color.autofill_dark_divider_color is not found.
12-16 17:18:46.747: W/XWalkInternalResources(8280): org.xwalk.core.R$color.autofill_divider_color is not found.
```

How to get rid of this issue?

Please help,

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, your `style`, `dimen`, `id` and `color` not configure inside `colors.xml`, `strings.xml` and `styles.xml`. And also your images not exist inside res `drawable` folder.

[image]

Comment: Its workaround. I can't manually change 3d party code only to get rid of warnings. thanks,